# iris (Go web framework) iris.PongoEngine error from iris official book

Tags: ubuntu, go, web, go-iris

I started using Golang's Web Framework (Iris). I'm using the official iris book from gitbooks.
I'm working on the [last example in this page](https://kataras.gitbooks.io/iris/content/hi.html) from the book.
Following is the code used in the last example

**./templates/hi.html**

```
<!-- ./templates/hi.html -->
<html><head> <title> Hi Iris [THE TITLE] </title> </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hi {{ Name }}
  </body>
</html>
```

**./main.go**

```
// ./main.go
import (
    "github.com/kataras/iris"
)

func main() {
    iris.Config.Render.Template.Engine = iris.PongoEngine
    iris.Get("/hi", hi)
    iris.Listen(":8080")
}

func hi(ctx *iris.Context){
   ctx.Render("hi.html", map[string]interface{}{"Name": "iris"})
}
```

When I run the main.go, following are the errors I got.

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:8: iris.Config.Render undefined (type *config.Iris has no field or method Render)
./main.go:8: undefined: iris.PongoEngine
```

I followed all the steps correctly, and also downloaded all the dependencies. I already took [Learn How To Code: Google's Go (golang) Programming Language - Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/learn-how-to-code/learn/v4/) and [Golang Workshop by Caleb Doxcy](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSak_q1UXfPrI6D67NF8ajfeJ6f7MH83S), so I know the basics, like how to install dependencies, and how to import them etc. But the example shown in the book doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like the API has been changed in master. The README recommends fetching the package via gopkg.in to get the V3 branch.

Comment: @JimB you mean I should reinstall iris (pull it from gopkg.in) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem with an offsite project's documentation, and not programming related.

Comment: yes, it looks like changing all import paths to `gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v3` will fix this issue (or you could checkout the V3 branch locally, and keep the import paths)

Comment: @JimB don't close it please.

Comment: @JimB I tried to install the framework from gopkg.in and it's giving problems in installation.

Comment: Then I would try checking out the V3 branch locally, and raise and issue with directly with the iris project. The README for that branch shows using gopkg.in https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import "github.com/kataras/iris/v12"

func main() {

    app := iris.New()
    app.RegisterView(iris.Django("./templates", ".html")) // <-----

    // RESOURCE: http://127.0.0.1:8080/hi
    // METHOD: "GET"
    app.Get("/hi", hi)

    app.Listen(":8080")
}

func hi(ctx iris.Context){
   ctx.ViewData("Name", "iris")
   ctx.View("hi.html")
}
```